# Loading resources from client assembly

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, image-loading

I'm currently creating a game engine and needed to load images from resources in the client assembly which references my library. I'm using this code.

```
public static Image LoadImageFromResource(string name){
    string asmname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).Replace('\\', '.').Replace('/', '.');
    MessageBox.Show(asmname);
    MessageBox.Show(asmname + "." + name.Replace('\\', '.').Replace('/', '.'));
/*164*/  return (Image)new Bitmap(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(asmname + "." + name.Replace('\\', '.').Replace('/', '.')));
}
```

And I'm calling this from the client test `GECS_TEST.exe`

```
/*11*/ Image img = Game.LoadImageFromResource("mario_left.png");
```

These are the outputs of the `MessageBox`

> GECS_TEST

> GECS_TEST.mario_left.png

And I'm getting this exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
   at GECS.Core.Game.LoadImageFromResource(String name) in C:\..\Game.cs:line 164
   at GECS_TEST.Test.Main(String[] args) in c:\..\Test.cs:line 11
```

Thanks

Comment: Your GetManifestResourceStream() seems to be null... are you compiling your project with a manifest?

Comment: I have set it to be `default manifest`. I have copied the resource into the package manager and selected it's build action as `Embedded Resource`

Comment: And also... if you have GECS and GECS_TEXT... why is EntryAssembly pointing to GECS_TEST? Try with GetCallingAssembly instead.

Comment: Because `GECS_TEST` project has a main method and is a exe. `GECS` is a class library

Comment: @Zarathos Thanks it solved. Why does this happen? Please add this as solution.

Comment: Try to debug with the new method. There were probably some incongruences with namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) instead of [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx).